Question about Environment Set in Universally Composable Security Proof
I have read into many papers and tutorials regarding "Universally Composable Security Proofs." I still have one confusion about the initial setup by the  environment. On one hand, I got that the environment makes the initial setup for all parties in both the ideal and the real worlds. In the initial setup, the private information must have been included and is known to the environment. For example, in multi-party key agreement protocol, the environment determines the values of the private random nonces for the individual participants involved in the key agreement protocol. On the other hand, I also got that "the environment and the adversaries can interact in arbitrary ways." I could not find the clear explanation that the environment will not provide private information (used during the initial setup) to the adversaries during the execution of the protocol. Can anyone point me to the right papers to allow me to see a more precise description about the fact that adversaries cannot directly obtain the private information from the environment through arbitrary interactions with the environment?

No, protocol instances have their own sources of randomness, from which secret key material and nonces are derived. If not, it would be hard to realize anything, for the reasons you discuss.

Thank you for the clarification. I think I should include a random oracle to determine the initial parameters for a session of a protocol. The random oracle is absolutely not corruptable and only provides blackbox access to others.

No, a random oracle does not model a randomness source, but rather a random-looking hash function. Like I said, protocol instances have their own sources of randomness, that is, their own random tape. There's no need for you to do anything to give your instances random nonces etc.
